# How can I access the inner functions of this script?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to Javascript, and am trying to figure out how to get to some inner functions in the following script:

https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/cd959903879588740de2f883dde34a8b12a47cba/dist/js/uikit.js

Basically, I want to manually trigger the `show` and `hide` commands of Offcanvas, at line 859, to bring in an offcanvas menu in `#offcanvas-nav`.

To me, it looks like the outer namespace would be `UI`, so my first thought was to reference that in a new file, after that main uikit.js file is loaded

```
function staticShow() {
  var UI = $.UIkit || {};
  var offcanvas_nav = jQuery.UIkit.offcanvas($('#offcanvas-nav'),{});
  ...
}
```

but I had no luck. Secondly I tried to access Offcanvas as a member of `jQuery.UIkit` but had similar results. How can I access the show/hide methods for the Offcanvas functions?

Another lesson I'd like to learn is what is happening at line 972,

```
})(jQuery, jQuery.UIkit, window.DocumentTouch);
```

I would bet my issues lie in not understanding that but I don't even know the Google phrase to search for. Thank you for any help.

Comment: For lesson two, google for `immediate functions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line 972 is calling the anonymous function at line 851

```
(function($, UI, DocumentTouch) {              //line 851
  //omitted
})(jQuery, jQuery.UIkit, window.DocumentTouch);//line 972
```

so within the function

- `$` = `jQuery`
- `UI` = `jQuery.UIkit`
- `DocumentTouch` = `window.DocumentTouch`

by looking at these lines

```
OffcanvasTrigger.offcanvas = Offcanvas; //line 953

UI["offcanvas"] = OffcanvasTrigger;     //line 955
```

`show` should be available here: `jQuery.UIkit.offcanvas.offcanvas.show`

Comment: ok thank you, that helped explain it--and thanks @marcel-gwerder for the `immediate functions` help, I understand that better now. To get this to work I had to specify the element to show, `jQuery.UIkit.offcanvas.offcanvas.show('#offcanvas-nav');`.